# how to unlock the index directory in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

how to unlock the index directory in  `lucene api 3.0` when using with the `SimpleFsFactory` in java?`unlock()` method is not working.i am new to using the `lucene`?

Comment: sure sir i will post the code

Comment: Thanks for the code. Would you mind posting the complete excpetion (incl. the stack trace)? I'm pretty sure it contains essential information about your problem.

Comment: This is the exception it is giving `org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException
 with message: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/mnt/Apps/docuHive/Docs/Index/write.lock `                                                              If we reload the project in tomcat manager page then only the lock is getting released. but i dont want to reload the project. And also tell me when to use `NativeFSLockFactory` and `SimpleFSLockFactory`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am doing it like this and it works for me:

```
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(folder);
    if (directory.fileExists(IndexWriter.WRITE_LOCK_NAME)) {
        directory.clearLock(IndexWriter.WRITE_LOCK_NAME);
        log.warn("Existing write.lock at [" + folder.getAbsolutePath() + "] has been found and removed. This is a likely result of non-gracefully terminated server. Check for index discrepancies!");
    }
    directory.close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not apply to lucene 5.x

Comment: The solution has actually stopped being relevant in Lucene 4 (not sure about the minor number). But the good news is that this problem itself is no longer relevant, see http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/261788#261788